# Java SerialPort communication, wrong input bytes on receiver

Tags: java, serial-port

When I`m sending bytes to receiver (using java), some of received byte values chaotically changing to 0x3F. (0x0 all the time changing to 0x3F)

java src:

```
serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);                       
  serialPort.openPort();
  serialPort.setParams(
    SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE
  );
  serialPort.writeBytes(new byte[]{0,3,(byte)240,1,(byte)242});
```

When I`m using arduino for data trasmission, everything works fine.

Arduino src:

```
byte b[5]={0,3,240,1,242};
void setup() { Serial.begin(9600);}
void loop() {
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    Serial.write(b[i]);
      delay(5);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

When I'm sending data from java to arduino, all bytes also looks fine.

When I'm sending data to receiver with VB or C# also - everything is fine.

When I'm sending data byte-by-byte with Thread.sleep(5) - no success.

What I`m doing wrong?

I`m using rxtx || jssc.

Current workaround - send data to receiver throught arduino. But its slow and wierd.

UPD:

After monitoring port activity:
Success packet has couple WAIT_ON_MASK functions (up,down)
Then in one function IRP_MJ_READ got all packet with proper bytes.

When I`m trying to send data with my java code, there is a lot SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS (up/down) functions, then IRP_MJ_READ with first 3 bytes converted to 0x3F, then again WAIT_ON_MASK & COMMSTATUS, and then remaing data byte-by-byte.

P.s.
Receiver is an old car bc.

Comment: `0x3F` is `?` in ASCII. This often indicates a *character* encoding problem, but since you're dealing with binary data it shouldn't be an issue. It may still be related somehow.

Comment: there is no ASCII, only bytes. But I'l check

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my comment. However if you're consistently getting bytes converted into `0x3F` (i.e. ASCII `?`) I have a hard time believing it to be just a coincidence.

Comment: are you trying to communicate via KW1281 protokoll?

Comment: No,the protocol is much simplier ibus (bmw)

Comment: So why are you using `Thread.sleep()`? Why are you deliberately wasting time, *especially* when it causes a bug?

Comment: I`m not using sleep in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case SerialPort.PARITY_EVEN (using jssc) solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

use jserialComm.jar file and arduino.jar file to communicate directly with serial monitor (google search or directly downlord from link https://youtu.be/GLX21Bf2kXI)

Step 1 : upload code in arduino

step 2 : download 2 jar files 
  1. jSerialComm
  2. arduino

step 3 : add this 2 jar files to your project and import arduino.* 
    e.g.  import arduino.*;

step 4 : create a new object of arduino by writing
     Arduino aa=new Arduino();

step 5 : initilise a port to the object of arduino bu using setPortDescription() method
  and pass a string of perticular port
   e.g.  aa.setPortDescription("COM4");
                              "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                                            "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
                                            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
                                            "COM3"or"COM4" // Windows

step 6 : open connection for communication by using openConnection(); method
  e.g.   aa.openConnection();

step 7 : to write or send command use method serialWrite(String);
  e.g.  aa.serialWrite("1");    //you can also use scanner function

step 8 : to read command from serial use serialRead(); method
  e.g.  aa.serialWrite();     this will return a string

step 9 : close the connection by using closeConnection() method 
   e.g.   aa.closeConnection();

Comment: how can it help me?

Comment: you can directly send a string to arduino

Comment: I`m not sending anything to arduino. I`m not working with arduino at all. I`m not sending "strings". My question in general - how can I send bytes using java without sign. (0 - 255) 
Arduino is only for monitoring bytes flow.